# How to apply a filter to data passed into a function?

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to call a function on a button click using Vue. I want to apply a filter to the data being passed into it since the function it will run requires the data to be formatted a certain way. Here is what I'm trying:

```
<button v-on:click="functionName(variable|filter)">icon</button>
```

but this doesn't work. The function will only call correctly without the filter. What is the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your filter as a function (either inside `methods` or outside anywhere in your script), and then you can simply call it and reuse its return value:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    filter(data) {
      return data * 2; // or anything
    },
    functionName(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="functionName(filter(1))">icon</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call `this.$options.filters.filterName` in your method

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    functionName(data) {
      console.log(this.$options.filters(data));
    }
  }
});
```

source: https://github.com/vuejs/Discussion/issues/405#issuecomment-142089920